# Is it possible to remove a conditional formatting rule created via ConditionalFormatRuleBuilder

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am making custom conditional formatting rules using this method: [ConditionalFormatRuleBuilder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/conditional-format-rule-builder).

However, If I ever update it, say the color in `.setBackground("#FF0000")`, and run it again, it creates a new conditional formatting rule that conflicts with the original one.

What I want to know, is in that example is there a way to remove the rule defined as rule? For example is there an opposite of `rules.push(rule);`? Something like `rules.remove(rule);` ?

Here's an example from my code. I currently have this:

```
var rule1 = SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
        .whenTextEqualTo(s1)
        .setBackground(s1c)
        .setRanges([r])
        .build();

var rules = curSheet.getConditionalFormatRules();
      rules.push(rule1);

curSheet.setConditionalFormatRules(rules);
```

Would it be possible to remove the rule defined as `rule1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you highlight your entire sheet and select Conditional Formatting from the menu, you will see a list of all of the active format rules on the right of the screen.

The order that the rules in that pane is the same order of the rules in the .getConditionalFormatRules() array.

So you can use splice() to remove which ever rule(s) you want

```
function deleteFormat(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var rules = sheet.getConditionalFormatRules();
  
  // if you want to remove rules starting at the 4th rule and delete only 1 rule. 
  rules.splice(3,1);
  sheet.setConditionalFormatRules(rules);
}
```

I tested it on a sample sheet, and it worked.  If you have any issues, add a comment and I will look into it.

Also, if you want to edit a rule programmatically, you can use slice with the builder.

1. Build your rules as normal
2. Get the list of rules
3. Use slice('position to remove', 1, newRule)
4. Set the rules

This will remove the old rule at that position in the array, and replace it with the new one.

Comment: This looks like what i'm looking for, I will test it shortly. However I would like to ask if you happen to know if it is possible to remove/replace a rule based on its condition rather than its place in the array? For instance, after doing .getConditionalFormatRules(), can I filter it by the conditions? For example "if the rule is exact text "test", remove it"

Comment: I could not find a way to access the contents of a rule through app scripts.